# Associatedtype Swift 3

Tags: ios, generics, swift3

I'm trying understand generics culture in **Swift** so I've written a small example. But it does not compile.

Error: **Generic parameter 'P' could not be inferred**
I can't understand for I'm doing wrong.

```
protocol Protocol_1 {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol Protocol_A {}
struct SomeStruct_2: Protocol_A {}

struct SomeStruct_1: Protocol_1 {
    typealias T = Protocol_A
}


let struct1 = SomeStruct_1()
testFunction(t: struct1) // *Generic parameter 'P' could not be inferred*

func testFunction<P: Protocol_1>(t: P) where P.T : Protocol_A {

}
```

Comment: [Protocols do not conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) in Swift, so you cannot use `Protocol_A` as a type that conforms to `Protocol_A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P.T in testFunction cannot conform to Protocol_A, but you can check if its equal to Protocol_A.

```
func testFunction<P: Protocol_1>(t: P) where P.T == Protocol_A {
}
```